# Adding Monogame to the existing Xamarin project

Tags: cross-platform, xamarin, monogame

A Xamarin newbie here. I have recently started developing a cross-platform mobile application using Xamarin with Visual Studio. There is now an idea to introduce an application framework to manage graphics and animations, such as Monogame. I've looked at the tutorials and it looks like that I had to start using Monogame from the beginning, as I couldn't find a way to use it with an existing project. So, I am wondering is there such a possibility at all?

Answer (score 0):

How are you wishing to integrate it? It is possible to instantiate a Game class from a button touch or some other user input. From that you point on you are solely inside of MonoGame until the game is closed. The only issue i came across with this is removing the game  and handing control back to the main application as this is not how MG was designed to be used.